# How to iterate over of an array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, struct, iteration, boundary

In my application I use an array of structs and I need to iterate over the array. What is the proper way to do it? How can I check if I have reached the end of the array?

```
// structure
struct MyData {
  int count;
  char name[20];
  float average;
}
```

I have tried iterating like this, but my application crashes:

```
struct MyData data[2] = { {3, "name1", 1.0}, {5, "name2", 2.5} };
struct MyData* ptr = data;

while (*ptr != NULL) {
  // print the contents, works ok for 2 elements

  ptr++; // increment the pointer
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### How is an array of structs allocated

In your case, the `MyData[2]` array looks like this in memory:

```
| count | name | average | count | name | average |
^ -- your ptr points here
```

This is a single, continuous space with size `2 * sizeof (struct MyData)`.

Whenever you perform a `ptr++` operation the pointer will move to the next structure in the array, which means that it takes into account the size of a single `struct MyData`.

```
| count | name | average | count | name | average |
                         ^ -- after ptr++ your ptr points here
```

After another `ptr++` your pointer will point to the memory *just after* your array.

```
| count | name | average | count | name | average | 
                                                  ^ -- another ptr++ and your ptr points here
```

**When you dereference your `ptr` pointer you access memory which is not yet used or even allocated. This is undefined behavior and because of that your application crashes.**

### How to iterate?

There are several ways to do it. Note that not all ways are applicable in all cases.

**A simple for**

Very often we simply know the size of the array. We can then just use a normal `for` loop to iterate over the contents.

```
int len = 2;
struct MyData data[len] = { {3, "name1", 1.0}, {5, "name2", 2.5} };
struct MyData* ptr = data;
for (int i=0; i<len; i++, ptr++ ) {
   // do your thing with the ptr
   // and note that ptr gets increased inside for
}
```

**Using sizeof to determine array length**

```
struct MyData data[2] = { {3, "name1", 1.0}, {5, "name2", 2.5} };
struct MyData* ptr = data;
struct MyData* endPtr = data + sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]);
while ( ptr < endPtr ){
   // do your thing with the ptr
   ptr++;
}
```

The `sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0])` calculates the amount of elements: gets the total size of an array and divides it by the size of a single element.

This method has its drawbacks. It can not be used when the array is declared as a pointer! For example, when we pass the array as a parameter to a function it usually gets converted to a pointer - and then we can not determine the size of the array.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any control on the size of the array and can even not ask for it, you could try reorganize your code, not using an array of `MyData` but an array of **pointers** to `MyData`.
Your array must then be one slot longer to store a guard with `NULL` value.

Your iteration will look like the one you wrote as an example.

```
// N is the number of MyData instances you have
MyData* vData[N+1];
// vData[i] is filled, and vData[N] = NULL

// ...

MyData* vPtr = vData[0];
while(vPtr) {
    // ...
}
```

But this involves changing the type of your array from `MyData[]` to `MyData*[]`. If you can't, you should follow Dariusz answer.

Comment: But the `while(vPtr)` shouldn't really be `while(vPtr++)` because as it is that will cause an infinite loop, also there should be a bounds check inside because if the struct is full the condition will never meet a NULL value